# boost_filesystemConfig.cmake file does not exist even though boost is installed

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am currently trying to compile some C++ code using CMake, which requires the boost libraries. I am using Ubuntu 18.04 on WSL, and have installed boost 1.77 using the following tutorial [1](https://cosmiccoding.com.au/tutorials/boost). I know that it works as I've successfully complied the examples using g++. I need to use CMake so that I can include header files from another library that uses Qt. When compiling I get the following error:

`CMake Error at /usr/lib/cmake/Boost-1.77.0/BoostConfig.cmake:141 (find_package):`                                                                 `Could not find a package configuration file provided by "boost_filesystem"`                                                                     `(requested version 1.77.0) with any of the following names:`                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     `boost_filesystemConfig.cmake`                                                                                                                   `boost_filesystem-config.cmake`                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               `Add the installation prefix of "boost_filesystem" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or`                                                                      `set "boost_filesystem_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above`                                                                          `files.  If "boost_filesystem" provides a separate development package or`                                                                       `SDK, be sure it has been installed.`                                                                                                          `Call Stack (most recent call first):`                                                                                                             `/usr/lib/cmake/Boost-1.77.0/BoostConfig.cmake:258 (boost_find_component)`                                                                       `CMakeLists.txt:32 (find_package)`                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           `-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!`

When I search through the ubuntu files I cannot find this one anywhere on the system, so I can't add it to my CMakeLists.txt file. I have also tried other similar solutions such as `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev` and other variations but they all say they are already installed on my machine. Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: If you followed the tutorial you refer to and executed `./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr/ --with-libraries=python`, then Boost is built **only with python** library included. Either remove `--with-libraries` option at all, or add `filesystem` into it. As for `libboost-all-dev` package on Ubuntu 18.04, the package and its dependencies contain none `.cmake` files.

Comment: Probably, the command `sudo ./b2 install` should list all files which it installs. You may examine output of that command and find out which `.cmake` files it installs.

Comment: I believe the problem should be fixed now as I realised I just did ./b2 rather than sudo ./b2 install when redoing this, and I can now see the .cmake files I need. Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo apt install libboost-filesystem-dev
```